# Integrate Kendoui Autocomplete inside Kendoui Scheduler templete

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-autocomplete

I am looking forward to add an kendoui autocomplete control in kendoui scheduler template. However, the below code does not make any call to get data for autocomplete textbox. I understand, it’s not wiring up any event.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
            <script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
               <h3>Edit meeting</h3>
               <p>
                   <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>
               </p>
               <p>
                   <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>
               </p>
               <p>
                   <label>End: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>
               </p>
               <p>
                   <label>Users: <input name="txtUsersAutoComplete" /></label>
               </p>
            </script>
            <div id="scheduler"></div>
            <script>
            $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
              date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
              editable: {
                template: $("#editor").html()
              },
              views: [
                { type: "day" }
              ],
              dataSource: [
                {
                  id: 1,
                  start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
                  end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
                  title: "Interview"
                }
              ]
            });
            </script>
            <script>
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              transport: {
                read: {
                  url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                  dataType: "jsonp"
                }
              }
            });
            $("#txtUsersAutoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
              dataSource: dataSource,
              dataTextField: "ProductName"
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: please check on your jquery selector and your dom, you are trying to select txtUsersAutoComplete as an Id but you actually set it as name there <label>Users: <input name="txtUsersAutoComplete" /></label>

Comment: @himawanraharja thanks for your response. I implemented AutoComplete inside Scheduler by putting code in "edit" section of Scheduler.

`$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({`
            `date: new Date(),`
            `edit: function (e) { `               
                `$("#txtUsersAutoComplete").kendoMultiSelect({`
                    `dataSource: dataSource,`
                    `dataTextField: "ProductName"`
                `});`
            `},`
`---`

Appreciate your time.